# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Is it possible to have a common config.xml for all environments?

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, phonegap-plugins

Using Worklight 6.0 on Eclipse Juno.

Problem is when I build Worklight project for all environments, config.xml is generated accordingly. Now, I have to make changes every time for Android & iPhone/iPad I have to manually add all the plugins list into it.

Is there any way that I can add it once in config.xml and have it used everywhere every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `config.xml` files for Android and iOS contain different structure and contents, so the answer is: No. You cannot have 1 `config.xml` for both environments.

And yes, you'll need to edit each of the files with the correct plug-in structure.

Next, I do not understand what do you mean by "every time"...

The files location is:

1. iOS: `native\config.xml`
2. Android: `native\res\xml\config.xml`

You will only need to edit these files if you either rename or delete your plug-in, or delete the native folder as a whole.

If you want, you can do the following:

1. For iOS: copy config.xml to the `iphone\nativeResources` folder
2. For Android: copy config.xml to the `android\nativeResources\res\xml` folder (if the folder doesn't exist, create it)

This way, if you ever delete the native folder, this file will be copied to it once you re-build the Worklight application.

You will still need to edit it (in the `nativeResources` folder(s)) if you ever need to remove or rename a plug-in.

Comment: Agree. I have my own 8 for Android & 12 for iOS - Cordova plug-in(s). So, Isn't there any other way to avoid this exercise every time?

Comment: What do you mean "every time"? See my updated answer.