# Worklight - FWLST1040E: ipad build failed: Cannot overwrite template file

Tags: ios, eclipse, ipad, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using worklight for my mobile app project using eclipse. My problem is I cant build ipad native. I got this error during build.

```
FWLST1040E: ipad build failed: com.worklight.builder.exception.WorklightBuildRuntimeException: Resource Manager - Problem reading info.plist file
```

I already use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396665/ibm-worklight-6-0-build-issues) technique but the problem still occur. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Delete the native folder
2. Close Eclipse
3. Open Terminal.app and write: `open $TMPDIR`
4. Delete the `wlBuildResources` folder
5. Open Eclipse
6. Build the application

Comment: What do you do if you've actually got native code that you don't want to delete?  Seems awfully heavy handed to delete the entire native folder.

Comment: I agree. You can use the nativeResources folder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481932/worklight-native-resources-not-loading-in-the-xcode-project/22482147#22482147 and also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453551/ibm-worklight-6-0-is-it-possible-to-have-a-common-config-xml-for-all-environme/21453642#21453642

Comment: The iPad 'environment' in eclipse doesn't have a nativeResources folder, plus we've added a significant number of frameworks and other build settings to the .xcodeproj file, all of which would be lost if we just nuke the native folder. Do I just copy all of my modified files in native over to nativeResources and let the WL build process overwrite things?

Comment: I don't know what's your Worklight version, but the iPad folder should have a nativeResources as well. After you build your project in Xcode you can then basically mirror the native folder structure in the nativeResources folder and since you will then have a pbxproj file with all the references and libs, it should work the next time you build the project in Eclipse and then open it Xcode. Everything should be linked... I suggest to experiment.

Comment: We're using 6.1. If we put our custom classes in nativeResource then do a Run As XCode Project it merges everything into the native directory and opens the project with all the code in the native directory. Now if I edit my Obj-C classes they are saved into the native directory. Seems like a recipe for loosing all of those native changes the next time I Run XCode project. Or are you suggesting avoid using XCode to edit my objective-C source? It just seems like the development cycle for native code is not optimal.

Comment: Indeed, if you will build again, what that you've put in the nativeresources folder will be copied again and you'll lose what's in the native, so you must re-copy it the updated files to the nativeresources folder again; it's not optimal, but you're using 2 IDEs, so...

Comment: I'll not comment how sub-optimal it is. I've added a script to the end of my XCode build project (XCode being the better IDE) that sync's the mutable files in native back to nativeResources:rsync -av --exclude='build' --exclude='CordovaLib' --exclude='Frameworks' --exclude='Settings.bundle' --exclude='Tealeaf' --exclude='WorklightSDK' --exclude='www' --exclude='buildtime.sh' --exclude='README.txt' --exclude='worklight.plist' --exclude='Resources' --exclude='build' --exclude='CVS' --exclude='FipsHttp' ../native/* ../nativeResources

Comment: Glad you've found a working flow for you. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I had deleted my iPad environment, but after I created a new one, I followed this, and it worked.

Try the following:

Delete the native folder
Close Eclipse
Open Terminal.app and write: open $TMPDIR
Delete the wlBuildResources folder
Open Eclipse
Build the application